# How does the ending of MIB2 reconcile with the ending of MIB?

Tags: men-in-black, men-in-black-2

At the end of *Men in Black*, the camera zooms out and we see that

> Earth , indeed our entire Galaxy and known Universe is, nothing more than the equivalent of an atom in a marble belonging to some aliens.

I always liked that ending, however it was seemingly voided by the end of *MIB2*.

At the end of *MIB2*, it is shown that,

> seemingly, at the least Earth is simply inside a locker or similar compartment belonging to a much larger species.

Is there any way to reconcile the two endings?

Answer (score 13):

One way to reconcile the endings is to think of the alien locker at the end of MIB2 as containing our *dimension*, a dimension with many scales in which the whole of our universe fits inside the marble of an alien in a larger universe, *which is still within the same dimension* and therefore all still within the alien locker. The alien locker is therefore a container for our *entire* dimension and the door to that locker enters the enclosed dimension on one of its smaller scales (i.e. ours).

Basically, you can think of the alien locker as being "dimensionally transcendental" like a [TARDIS](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/TARDIS) from [Doctor Who](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who), with an interior that exists in a different dimension than the exterior and thus having the ability to be different sizes on the inside and outside.

Comment: For our entire dimension to be in that locker, wouldn't it need to fold in on itself? It would make sense if the locker door was a portal, but it was implied we were actually inside a locker. How would that work with Earth being in free space?

Comment: @KirstyMcNair - Dimensionally transcendental... Think of it this way. The locker door is dimensionally linked to that specific door on earth. The earth is still in space. The example of TARDIS is actually perfect. The TARDIS door isn't a portal, yet entering the TARDIS, we have these entire palace, which has no physical existence outside the TARDIS.