# Why does it take so long to translate the Arquillian message?

Tags: men-in-black

Between the battle cruisers arriving,  and translating four words (if "MIB" counts) K and J manage to have the confrontation at the jewellery shop.

This seems like it takes a long time to translate their message, doesn't it?

Add to this that we see one of them speaking English...

[image: Gentle Rosenberg, member of threes royal house, in his head-machine]

Why does it take so long?

Comment: [Hey, old guys!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xebEj0rV6m0)

Comment: Could the downvoter please let me know how to improve my question? I think the photo helps considering I've said one of them was taking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implication seems to be that there weren't any massive problems with the translator, just that the message being translated made no sense. That would have made them mistrust whatever else it was saying.

The situation is slightly clearer in the book's [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2010110.Men_In_Black)

> "What about the Arquillians?" Kay said.
>
> "Apparently we're still having some problems with the Arquillian
>   cross-dictionary in our translator. We've only gotten part of the
>   message so far. Says, 'Deliver the galaxy.' "
>
> "Great. Wonderful. Nobody knows what the hell is going on."

Comment: That **does** sounds like a problem with the translator (albeit due to  the dictionary). What is a *cross dictionary* (and why is it mad) ? Also I figured you'd be able to answer,  add I've seen you've got the novelisation in other answers you've posted. Thanks.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I think they just mean "translation dictionary" unless they're needing to translate it from one alien language into another before translating it into English.

Comment: Of note, our galaxy is just one of many of what they would consider marbles. There's definitely room for translation errors.

Comment: @phantom42 - There's no indication that the Arquillians view our galaxy as a marble. The sequence at the end I don't think is meant to be taken literally.

Comment: No indication other than the movie showing them playing marbles with our galaxy. Even if you don't think it's meant to be taken literally, how can you possibly say that there's "no indication"?

Comment: @phantom42 - Worthy of its own question; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12196/how-does-the-ending-of-mib2-reconcile-with-the-ending-of-mib

Comment: Ah, it's our *universe* that's a marble, not just our galaxy. And there's no indication that the Arquillians are in any way aware.